# 'None' type error when importing function

Tags: python

I am trying to import the answer of a function. The function is this:

```
def flo(rate,length, interval, threshold):
    data = []          #to create an empty list 
    new  = [rate[i:i+ length] for i in range(0, len( rate)-len( rate) %  length ,  length)]      
    for i in range(len(new )):
            data.append('True')  
            print(data)
    return 


flo( rate,length, interval, threshold)
```

where I got the output:

```
[False]
[False, False]
[False, False, True]
[False, False, True, True]
[False, False, True, True, True]
[False, False, True, True, True, False]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, True]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
```

Now I want to import this answer into another function. So I did:

```
import flow_rate  as flow

z = flow.flow_rate ( rate,  length, interval, threshold)    
print(z)
```

But my output is:

```
None
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are not returning anything. You just put ```return``` which returns None

Comment: The `return` at the end of your function doesn't return any variables from inside your function. You need to use `return data` at the end of your function.

Comment: ```return data```. This will be the answer

Comment: @Sujay@Craig thank you very much. I was wondering why it wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply put a `return` statement. There is not variable after `return`, so `None` is getting returned. It is as good as the `return`statement is not present in the function.

So you need to return the data:

```
return data
```